# How is a volume of space with a null magnetic field created in a lab?

Tags: electromagnetism

My question is how a space without magnetism can be created in a laboratory?

Comment: Do you mean superconductors , as in this video https://youtu.be/zPqEEZa2Gis

Comment: I don't know for sure. I have heard of the use of 3 orthogonal [Helmholtz coils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_coil), but that has limitations.

Comment: Vote To Close as unclear as to the nature of the question.

Comment: I think the question is clear enough: OP is asking how to shield something from external magnetic fields (as a Faraday cage or something of the sort).

Answer (score 1):

Given that you will always have the influence of the Earth's field plus any variable field produced by electric current sources nearby (for instance a 50 or 60 Hz, depending on where you live, will always be present) you will need two things. The first one is some sort of Faraday cage and a set of three orthogonal coils counteracting any remaining field (since the Faraday cage will most probably be unable to completely isolate the external fields).

Under these conditions, you will only have a zero magnetic field near the center of your coils.

Comment: Yeah, this is essentially it. However, it bears mention that a huge class of atomic physics experiments that do this - they require zero magnetic field to work - but they are still very sensitive to magnetic field *noise*. This comes from stray fields from e.g. electronics in the lab, is very hard to guard against,  and they are very often the limiting factor to getting better precision.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain materials (steel and mu-metal, for example) that have high magnetic permeability, which means that, when they are placed in a magnetic field, the field lines stay inside the material. This means that, if you make a box out of this material, any magnetic field outside the box will enter the material of the box and be confined to it. This routes the field lines around the interior of the box, leaving the space inside the box with zero electric field. You can see this effect with a steel plate (center) and box (right) in the picture below. If the magnet is placed inside the box, the outside of the box is shielded since the field lines will be trapped in the box walls.

[image: Magnets and shielding]

Picture from here: https://www.kjmagnetics.com/blog.asp?p=shielding-materials